# How to read local packages folder using NuGet?

Tags: nuget

I am trying to read my local solution `packages` folder using `NuGet.Core`.

If I create `new UnzippedPackageRepository(pathToPackages)` and call `GetPackages()` on it, the result is empty. I am looking at the source of `UnzippedPackageRepository` and it has:

```
from file in FileSystem.GetFiles("", "*" + Constants.PackageExtension)
let packageName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
where FileSystem.DirectoryExists(packageName)
select new UnzippedPackage(FileSystem, packageName)
```

So it seems to expect `*.nupkg` for each package in top level?

Anyway, what is right way to read solution package store aside from going through each folder and creating `UnzippedPackage` manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it, solution `packages` folder is handled by `SharedPackageRepository`.